# Mahout MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel issue

Tags: mahout-recommender

I am trying to generate recommendation on a table having no preference value but it always gives error like "DataModel doesn't have preference values".
                        I have created Boolean datamodel as shown below why it is giving this error.Please help me to resolve this issue.I am attaching code for my database connection and datamodel creation as below.

```
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource ();
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setUser("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("******");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("recommendation");

        MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel dataModel = new MySQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel(dataSource,"test","user_id","song_id", null);
```

I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537322/how-to-make-a-more-efficient-recommender-in-mahout but faced same problem

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, could you please share . Thanks